# DOMXPath - Inconsistent results from 2 xpath queries that are the same

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

I am having a weird error when using DOMXpath.

When I am using DOMXPath->query, the first call always fails while the second call doesn't.
This is even when I am using the same xpath on both queries

```
$html_dom    = new DOMDocument();
@$html_dom->loadHTML($html);
$x_path = new DOMXPath($html_dom);

$nodes = $x_path->query("//table/tr[3]/td[2]");
echo $nodes->length; // returns 0, which is not correct

// Type
$nodes = $x_path->query("//table/tr[3]/td[2]");
echo $nodes->length; // returns 17, which is the correct value
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: What happen if you remove the `@`?

Comment: Can you also provide the (minimized version of) `$html` that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: @Passerby http://pastebin.com/7ZaC7j9q Keep in mind that I have no control over the markup.

Comment: I copied your HTML to localhost (because I don't seem to be able to remote-fetch it from pastebin) and parse it with your code, and the result is two 17s, instead of 0 and 17.

Comment: Can you post your php version?

Comment: Well I am using PHP Version 5.3.5. No major version difference so that is not an issue too.